# async.js : async.eachSeries result always throw undefined

Tags: javascript, async.js

Is there something wrong with my code?, I use `async.eachSeries` but my result always throw undefined.

Here my code :

```
async.eachSeries([1,2,3], function(data, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb(null, data+1);
    }, 1000);
}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(err, result);
});
```

My log returned : `null`, undefined instead of `null`, `[2,3,4]`

thanks... and sorry for my terrible english XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument is called when the iteration is done and with `eachSeries()`, it takes only one parameter, `err`. If you want `result`, you have to use `mapSeries`:

```
async.mapSeries([1, 2, 3],
    function (data, cb) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            cb(null, data + 1);
        }, 1000);
    },
    function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks... I just noticed it... that eachSeries doesnt have result parameter XD

Answer (score 1):

You can use a form of result with eachSeries() as well:

```
var result = [];
async.eachSeries([1,2,3], function(data, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        result.push(data+1);
        cb(null);
    }, 1000);
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err, result);
});
```

That should work, although I'm not able to test it myself at the moment.

Comment: `mapSeries` exists for this case.

Comment: yeah... this method a bit tricky but work... I tested it.. but I think I will use @ShanShan method. 
thanks for your answer btw XD

Comment: I know @ShanShan, just figured I'd provide an answer using the OPs method. :)